# Angular 2 Display issues with ngIf inside ngFor

Tags: angular

Has anyone seen display issues while nesting either ngSwitch/ngIf directives inside ngFor in angular 2?

```
<ng-container *ngIf="allowedActions">
  <button *ngFor="let action of displayActions(row)" mat-menu-item>
    <ng-container *ngIf="action === 'publish'">
      <i class="material-icons md-24">mdi-publish</i> Publish Collection
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="action === 'security'">
      <i class="material-icons md-24">mdi-security</i> Collection Security
    </ng-container>
  </button>
</ng-container>
```

is displaying like:

[image]

console output

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Could you add a bit more about the problem? What's your expected vs actual? Some screenshots may be super obvious for you but not so for others.

Comment: Make a stackblitz

Comment: How many items are returned by `displayActions(row)` and what is the type of `action`?

Comment: you dont need inner ng-containers

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not about Angular but material-icons.

Try removing `mdi-` in `<i class="material-icons md-24">mdi-publish</i>` as the following codes.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="allowedActions">
   <button *ngFor="let action of displayActions(row)" mat-menu-item>
   <ng-container *ngIf="action === 'publish'">
     <i class="material-icons md-24">publish</i> Publish Collection
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="action === 'security'">
     <i class="material-icons md-24">security</i> Collection Security
   </ng-container>
 </button>
</ng-container>
```

Will results like this

[image]

Reference on [https://material.io](https://material.io/icons/#ic_publish)